# Chating app in iOS with push notification

Tags: node.js, swift, socket.io, apple-push-notifications, chat

I'm building a chatting application in iOS, I'm going to implement it using Node.js and Socket.IO for my backend.

I'm trying to implement push notification to notify the user of new message when they are not in the app.

Do I send the notification for every message sent and ignore the push notification when inside the app or is there a way to only send the push notification when the user has exited the app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you using socket communicate server and client, so you can have a check mechanism.

Client A send message to B.

Sever received the message and check if B was online(connected to server):
Yes: just send message using the socket B connected
No: push notification to B